# ios nsuserdefaults sync

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, synchronization

Hi I have arrays saved in NSUserDefaults in my ios application.
I want to create a two way sync to get data from the sql server and store it in this database as well as updating the server with this database.
How would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a little better. I think I understand what you are trying to do.

First, you will need to create a server side page that will display the data you want to store on the iPhone in `NSUserDefaults`. I would recommend having the page display the data output in json format, then use a JSON Parser library like SBJSON to parse the data into an `NSArray` then you store this information in NSUserDefaults. To get this data you can use an `NSURLConnection`.

To send data to the server it's much of the same thing you will need to use `NSURLConnection` to send the data back to the server either via POST or GET methods.